# How to parse df line-by-line?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I would like to parse the output from `df` so I do

```
arr=( $(df -hPT | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $7}') )
for f in ${arr[@]}; do echo ${f[*]};sleep 1;done
```

but I get

```
Filesystem
Size
Avail
Use%
Mounted
devtmpfs
7.8G
7.8G
0%
/dev
tmpfs
7.8G
7.7G
3%
```

where I had hoped for

```
Filesystem Size Avail Use% Mounted
devtmpfs 7.8G 7.8G 0%
/dev tmpfs 7.8G 7.7G 3%
```

My plan was that `$f` would be an array for each line, so I can manipulate each line and `printf` the output aferwards.

**Question**

Any ideas how I can get an array of the `awk` output per `df` line?

Comment: shouldn't `df -hPT | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $7}'`be enough to get your expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** In single `while` loop:

```
df -hPT | while read first second third fourth fifth sixth seventh
do
   echo $first $second $third $fifth $sixth $seventh
   sleep 1
done
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Following single `awk` may help you on same.

```
df -hPT | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $7;system("sleep 1")}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use while read... loop

```
df -hPT | while read line ; do echo "$line" | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $7}' ;sleep 1 ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bash builtin `mapfile` to store the lines of a file/stream into an array:

```
mapfile -t lines < <(df -hPT | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $7}')
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    manipulate "$line"
done
```

Need to redirect from the [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) so we don't introduce any subshells.

You've seen what happens when you fail to [quote the variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) in the for loop: **always** quote your variables (unless you know exactly why not).

Answer (score 0):

If you set IFS to \n like that :

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(df -hPT | \
  awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $7}') )
for f in ${arr[@]}; do
  echo ${f[*]}
done
echo "nb elt in arr = ${#arr[@]}"
```